# salesforce tag on SO - should we change it to advertise?

Tags: discussion, tags, stackexchange

On a chat on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge I started to ask what about SO questions.

They offered the following example of what android did

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android

and I thouhgt, ok, we can do that.

Off course we will need the mods cooperation here, but what should the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/salesforce say ?

Comment: There's already a note referring them here, no?  But I did notice more new q's there in the past day than there are here.  My guess is most people don't even notice the tag description when posting a q.

Comment: Is their any way to relocate any new questions from SO to SFSE when they are tagged salesforce? Either that or do we just need to do a comment campaign on SO pointing people here?

Comment: My problem is that every SF question would mostly fit SO, it's for devs, and most q's here are dev's related.  I can't comment on the oh-comment-atron you have suggested, for dimaond-related reasons :-)

Comment: I disagree, @Saariko. I thought this site was supposed to be all Salesforce, not just development, and would support general admin/setup/configuration questions. Right now the site is developer heavy, but I think that can and should change.

Comment: @MikeChale I agree with you, but that does not mean that q's from SO on dev, should not be here.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to see the SO Salesforce tag mention this site, preferably directing all traffic over. Is there any reason to post a new SF specific question on SO at all?

Comment: according to mods, they will only migrate q's that are not SO, but that will leave dev q's on SO. IT's tricky..

Answer (score 2):

Dragging this up again. I have noticed the message exists but is out of date. we are now public beta :)

Comment: And I have just realised, I can propose an edit. Which I have done